# Drawing ROS markerArrays using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, ros, rviz

I have a ROS bag file with markerArray markers that I am trying to draw on an image (so I can use as bounding boxes later on).

The data is for a trip from a vehicle (getting on the freeway ramp, driving around, then exiting the freeway).

Here is what the markers look like in RViz (My vehicle is the middle cube with 3.40m):

[image]

I tried to draw the CUBE markers (red cubes) using OpenCV with the following code:

```
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <rosbag/view.h>
#include <visualization_msgs/MarkerArray.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Open the ROS bag file
  rosbag::Bag bag;
  bag.open("/home/myuser/001.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Read);

// Specify the topic that contains the marker array data
std::vector<std::string> topics;
topics.push_back("/dataTopic/objects_marker");

// Create a view of the ROS bag file containing the specified topic
rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));

// Create a directory to store the image frames
std::string image_dir = "/home/myuser/ros_markers/image_frames";
if (!boost::filesystem::exists(image_dir))
{
  boost::filesystem::create_directory(image_dir);
}

// Loop through the messages in the view
int frame_num = 0;
for (rosbag::MessageInstance const msg : view) {
  // Convert the message to a marker array
 visualization_msgs::MarkerArray::ConstPtr markers = msg.instantiate<visualization_msgs::MarkerArray>();

if (markers != NULL) {
  // Create an empty image to draw the markers on
  cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(480, 640, CV_8UC3);

  // Loop through the markers in the array
  for (int i = 0; i < markers->markers.size(); i++) {
    // Get the marker properties
    int id = markers->markers[i].id;
    int type = markers->markers[i].type;
    // Create a YUV422 color from the RGB values

    cv::Scalar color(8, 8, 240, 1);
    // Draw the marker on the image
    if (type == visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE) {
      cv::Point3d position(markers->markers[i].pose.position.x, markers->markers[i].pose.position.y,
                           markers->markers[i].pose.position.z);

      cv::Vec3d scale(markers->markers[i].scale.x, markers->markers[i].scale.y, markers->markers[i].scale.z);
      cv::Matx33d rotation(markers->markers[i].pose.orientation.w, markers->markers[i].pose.orientation.z,
                           -markers->markers[i].pose.orientation.y,
                           -markers->markers[i].pose.orientation.z, markers->markers[i].pose.orientation.w,
                           markers->markers[i].pose.orientation.x,
                           markers->markers[i].pose.orientation.y, -markers->markers[i].pose.orientation.x,
                           markers->markers[i].pose.orientation.w);

      cv::Vec3d half_scale = scale * 2;

      // 8 points because Cube markers have 8 vertices
      cv::Vec3d points[8] = {cv::Vec3d(half_scale[0], half_scale[1], half_scale[2]),
                             cv::Vec3d(-half_scale[0], half_scale[1], half_scale[2]),
                             cv::Vec3d(half_scale[0], -half_scale[1], half_scale[2]),
                             cv::Vec3d(-half_scale[0], -half_scale[1], half_scale[2]),
                             cv::Vec3d(half_scale[0], half_scale[1], -half_scale[2]),
                             cv::Vec3d(-half_scale[0], half_scale[1], -half_scale[2]),
                             cv::Vec3d(half_scale[0], -half_scale[1], -half_scale[2]),
                             cv::Vec3d(-half_scale[0], -half_scale[1], -half_scale[2])};

      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        points[j] = rotation * points[j] + cv::Vec3d(position.x, position.y, position.z);
      }
      cv::Point image_points[8];
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        image_points[j] = cv::Point(points[j][0], points[j][1]);
      }
      cv::fillConvexPoly(image, image_points, 8, color);
    }
  }

  // Write the image to a file
  std::string image_path = image_dir + "/" + std::to_string(frame_num) + ".png";
  cv::imwrite(image_path, image);

  // Increment the frame number
  frame_num++;
  }
}
// Close the ROS bag file
bag.close();

return 0;
}
```

And this is what the drawn markers look like:

[image]

Now I understand that the issue might be the markers are recorded in real-world transform coordinates, therefore they are being drawn this way.

If I am drawing them correctly in my code, could someone tell if there is a way to draw them in camera transform coordinates (to view them from a front view from my vehicle looking ahead at the road)?

Thank you!

Edit:

Here is a data example of one of my markerArray markers:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 1657906813.396054877
  frame_id: vehicle_frame
ns: radar only
id: 44490
type: 1
action: 0
pose: 
  position: 
    x: 3.26551
    y: 18.9191
    z: 0.7
  orientation: 
    x: 0
    y: 0
    z: -0.0441122
    w: 0.999027
scale: 
  x: 1
  y: 1
  z: 1.4
color: 
  r: 1
  g: 0
  b: 0
  a: 0.7
```

Comment: Use the information from the tf-tree to transform the data. You can also check in which frame the coordinates are given, by checking `msg.header.frame_id`. You can get the transform between two connected frames with [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2). The data is available because rviz needs this as well to draw it correctly.

Comment: @Darkproduct could you explain what you mean by the information from the tf-tree? I am going to edit the post and add an example of a marker. My `pose` position and orientation data are in the `vehicle_frame`.

Comment: Look at [the link to the tf2 docu](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2) from my comment. You can [visualize the tf frames in rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/TF). You can also visualize your tf-tree using `rqt` and the tf-tree viewer plugin.